# pgrouting to calculate distance using a chosen highway system

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I am working on a research to calculate the distance of firms (scattering around the nation) to several metropolises via selected national highway system.

Then I overlay the highway map with firms' location. I have a sample map that is zoomed in to Beijing's map that encompasses both highway and firms: 
[image]

The purple lines are national highway system captured by the city map (Beijing ) and black dots represent firms' location. My research wants to calculate the distance of firms to another major city (now as a test, I just need to calculate the distance of firms in Beijing to Shanghai.

I follow a post by underdark to calculate the shortest path from a point to another point via a selected path. I am a newbie to pgrouting and the programming. I have some trouble to generate nodes ID and calculate the shortest path.

This is the table of my highway data: 
[image]

And this is my coding to generate nodes ID:

```
        CREATE VIEW highway_ext AS
    SELECT *, ST_StartPoint(geom), ST_EndPoint(geom)
    FROM highway

CREATE TABLE node1 AS
   SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY foo.p)::integer AS id, 
          foo.p AS geom
   FROM (         
      SELECT DISTINCT highway_ext.ST_StartPoint AS p FROM highway_ext
      UNION
      SELECT DISTINCT highway_ext.ST_EndPoint AS p FROM highway_ext
   ) foo
   GROUP BY foo.p;
```

This is my codes to do a shortpath calc:

```
   CREATE TABLE network1 AS
   SELECT a.*, b.id as ST_start_id, c.id as ST_end_id
   FROM highway_view AS a
      JOIN node AS b ON a.ST_StartPoint = b.the_geom
      JOIN node AS c ON a.ST_EndPoint = c.the_geom;

      SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('
   SELECT gid AS id, 
          ST_start_id::int4 AS source, 
          ST_end_id::int4 AS target, 
          shape_leng::float8 AS cost
   FROM network',
1,
5110,
false,
false);
```

As a result, my nodes table is like nothing

Any idea how should I generate node ID and Edge ID? What else do I need to address them?

Comment: I used [osm2pgrouting](https://github.com/pgRouting/osm2pgrouting), which does this for you. I know that isn't what you asked, but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

1) never use geometry (inlcuding point) for joining.  Too many floating point precision issues with that.

2) I see your geometries are MULTILINESTRING, bad never use this for routing your the_geom should be of type LINESTRING
- in PostGIS 2.0 ST_StartPoint / EndPoint will return NULL when applied to MULTILINESTRING and its just generally slower since pgrouting will just take the first geometry.  If you really have MULTILINESTRING you should use ST_Dump to convert them to linestrings:

I'm going to assume that all your MULTIs are really a single wrapped in a multi, to be sure run this query and it shouldn't return anything

```
SELECT * FROM highways WHERE ST_NumGeometries(the_geom) > 1;
```

If you get any - dump these out so separate records

If you have all singles, do this to convert your column:

```
 ALTER TABLE highway 
   ALTER COLUMN the_geom geometry(LINESTRING, 4326) USING ST_GeometryN(the_geom,1);
```

For future to prevent this, when loading with shp2pgsql use the -S switch to bring in as single linestrings (it will error if you have true multis)

You should use pgr_createTopology to generate the node table and populate source and target.

So

```
ALTER TABLE highway ADD COLUMN source integer;
ALTER TABLE highway ADD COLUMN target integer;
SELECT pgr_createTopology('highway', 0.00001);
```

The 0.00001 is tolerance in units of your spatial ref sys.  The pgr_createTopology does what you are trying to do - it will populate source and target (treating start and end points within tolerance as the same node) and create a nodes table highway_vertices_pgr

By the way this is all covered in our upcoming book which you can purchase draft now (we are about 75% done)

http://locatepress.com/pgrouting

so you'll get updates on each draft we publish and final when completed.